# Magento 2 custom Checkout Step

Tags: magento2, checkout, custom-field

I am creating a custom checkout step in Magento to allow customers to pick a delivery date based on their postcode,

I have already created the extra step, but I want to be able to pass the postcode that the customer enters from step 1 to step 2 so I can then give a shipping date option based on the customer's postcode,

just wondered what's the best way to pass the data from step 1 to step 2 $_post $_session? cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should already be saved in the data since postcode is a standard M2 field.

You should be able to access it in php by:

```
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
) {
    $this->addressInformation = $addressInformation;
}

$addressInformation->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
```